# Gitkraken won't open gui

Tags: 18.04, gui, git

When I try to run gitkraken, the app does not open. This is a brand new installation of Ubuntu 18.04. When run in the terminal it puts out this:

```
Gtk-Message: 23:23:20.033: Failed to load module "canberra-gtk-module"
Node started time: 1530167000243
libgnome-keyring.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
Error: libgnome-keyring.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
    at process.module.(anonymous function) [as dlopen] (ELECTRON_ASAR.js:172:20)
    at Object.Module._extensions..node (module.js:598:18)
    at Object.module.(anonymous function) [as .node] (ELECTRON_ASAR.js:186:18)
    at Module.load (module.js:503:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:466:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:458:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:513:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/share/gitkraken/resources/app.asar/node_modules/keytar/lib/keytar.js:4:12)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/share/gitkraken/resources/app.asar/node_modules/keytar/lib/keytar.js:58:4)
```

There are questions like this one but mine is not the same and has a different error message. I have tried the proposed fixes for the other ones.

Comment: try installing `libgnome-keyring0` package

Comment: @Arun haha that actually worked... wow I am a moron. thanks, post it as an answer so I can approve it and give you credit. Thanks for giving me the slap in the face I needed!

Answer (score 39, accepted):

`Gitkraken` depends on `libgnome-keyring0` package to manage keyrings. So install `libgnome-keyring0` package

```
sudo apt install libgnome-keyring0
```